# Update specific location of file separated by specific character in JAVA

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I am trying to do txt based database system. I'm stuck here now. What I want to do is enter the location of the data and then update it. I separate the data with this character. "|"

Structure like this:

```
ID |Name |Job     |Phone Number
---+-----+--------+------------
55 |John |Plumber |555444
```

The id part is to find out which row it is in, and the name part is in the column.

```
data_Update(filename, id, "Name", "Bob Ross");
```

I want to do a function like this.

Comment: What have you tried yourself ?

Comment: @Tarun I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: @ErcanAcar Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: @Progman I'm not new here but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in following manner:

Read the file and for each line of text add a entry in your HashMap

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,Object>> personMap
```

Where key represent Id of the person, And Value represent mapping of field name to field value for the current entry.

In your db_update method, locate the person by id and update e.g.

```
personMap.get(Id).put(fieldname,value)
```

Comment: I just want to update the data for multiple use of the program. How else can I do it and thanks for your help.

Comment: @ErcanAcar What do you mean by "multiple use"

Comment: I am talking about running the program at the same time and doing different operations. I am doing bank system.

Comment: @ErcanAcar for multiple operation on txt based database at the time same time, you will have to ensure it complies with ACID property. Easiest way would be to don't close file handle until operation of one user gets completed. But this will not be efficient.